# English sentence to FOL

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I was given a sentence ;

```
All students who are doing chemistry or biology can sit for some test.
```

According to my understanding I translated it in to first order logic;

```
∀x[ doing( student(x), chemistry) ∨  doing( student(x), biology) ] → ∃y can_sit(test(y), x)
```

Please tell me whether I'm correct or if not how to get the correct predicate.

Answer (score 3):

> All students who are doing chemistry or biology can sit for some test.

First, you should check if $x$ is a student or you'll target *anything*.
Your problem is not so complicated, so instead of a 'doing' predicate use a specific activities. Same with 'can sit for'.
And here is the final version:
$$
\forall x( isStudent(x) \wedge ( doingChemistry(x) \lor doingBiology(x) ) \implies canSitForATest(x) )
$$

Comment: 'x can sit for some test' contains a quantified NP whose existential force should be preserved by translating the quoted phrase into a quantified formula: $\exists y Txy$. So, the whole sentence gets translated as $\forall x(Sx \wedge (Cx \lor Bx) \rightarrow \exists y Txy)$

Comment: @Jon : Thank you very much.